Automating Video Creation in Blender with Python
I’m a beginner working on a Python script to create videos similar to this **[Instagram video : https://www.instagram.com/p/DEFyYNQorPm/
The idea is to input an Arabic voice-over and automate:

Syncing animated text with the audio (highlighting important words dynamically).
Generating or using images to match the voice-over content.
Possibly turning images (like buildings) into simple 3D models.
Adding procedural animations and sound design automatically.

I’d love to hear suggestions on the best pipeline to approach this! Tools, add-ons, or libraries that could simplify this process would be really helpful.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
